# How to play MP3 in GUI using PyQT

Tags: javascript, user-interface, pyqt, mp3

I wanted to create a simple GUI app which selects one of the MP3 files and plays it. Can't seem to find the best library for doing that with PyQT. Therefore need some recommendation on it. Don't mind switch to JavaFX or something if it has more options.

I know GUI is probably outdated nowadays when everything is web. Would Javascript be a better choice?

Comment: You can use `<input type="file">` element and `<audio>` element or Web Audio API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [vlc module for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-vlc) to play all types of audio and videos in case needed later. You should make use of the Qt example seen in examples folder when you unzip the downloaded tar file